# Get the dot product of two vectors by functors and STL algorithms

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I'm learning how to use functors together with STL algorithms to calculate the dot product of two vectors. Here are my codes:

```
template<size_t DIM>
double Vector<DIM>::operator*(const Vector<DIM>& rhs) const {
    double dotPro = 0;
    std::for_each(vec, vec + DIM, std::bind2nd(dot_product<double>(rhs.get()), dotPro));
    return dotPro;
}
/*vec is a double array and the data member of Vector class. I want to get the 
dot product of rhs and *this by using std::for_each(). 
rhs.get()returns a const double* which is the start address of rhs's vec*/

/*The codes below define the functor.  dotPro is passed as a reference so as to 
it could be save the last result.*/  
template<typename T>
struct dot_product: public std::binary_function<T, T, void> {
    const T* arg;
    sum(const T* dbl) : arg(dbl){};
     void operator() (const T dbl, T& dotPro) {
        dotPro += *arg++ * dbl;
    }
};
```

Sorry I forget my quesion...
The question is my code doesn't compile. Here is the compiling error:

```
error: no match for call to '(const dot_product<double>) (const double&, const double&)'|
note: candidates are: void dot_product<T>::operator()(T, T&) [with T = double]|
```

And here is a error occurs in binders.h

```
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\backward\binders.h|147|error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'|
```

Comment: There's no question.

Comment: How did this get +1 ? There's no question.

Comment: Yep. You've forgotten to ask a question. If it's not working as expected, tell us *how* the results differ to your expectations. If there's a compiler error, tell us what it is and where the compiler highlights. If you want a critique of the code, SO isn't the right place (maybe try code review)

Comment: A question requires _at least_ a question mark.

Comment: "Codes" refers to zero, two or more CPU opcodes in this context, but that form would only be relevant if you posted actual machine code, which would be... well, weird. Generally, when writing about code in programming meaning, you write "code", because it's neither "a[n op]code" nor "[op]codes" in most cases.

Comment: did you read the error in binders.h? it's quite clear...

Comment: dot product is std::inner_product - http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/inner_product.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [std::inner_product](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/inner_product.html):

[live demo](http://ideone.com/c6B4Ci)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1,v2;
    generate_n( back_inserter(v1), 256, rand );
    generate_n( back_inserter(v2), v1.size(), rand );
    cout << inner_product( v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), 0 ) << endl;
}
```

---

> Yes, that's a good solution. But I don't want to use any methods provided in numeric.h.

Just define your own dot_product:

[live demo](http://ideone.com/evIZZ7)

```
template<typename InputIterator1,typename InputIterator2,typename ValueType>
ValueType dot_product( InputIterator1 first, InputIterator1 last, InputIterator2 another, ValueType init)
{
    while(first!=last)
    {
        init += (*first) * (*another) ;
        ++first;
        ++another;
    }
    return init;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good solution. But I don't want to use any methods provided in numeric.h.